# What material are High Pressure Compressors made of?

Tags: jet-engine, aerospace-materials

What material are GE engine High Pressure Compressor (spools) made of ? i.e. aluminum, titanium ?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE. This question is oddly specific, I think that an answer will be difficult to come by unless a GE engineering passes by and the answer is not a trade secret.

Comment: Most aero-engine compressors are fabricated in various titanium alloys. Some fixed turbine installations use a stainless steel alloy for which GE have a patented aluminium-based anti-corrosion coating. You can find more details in [this document](http://www.intechopen.com/download/pdf/22905)

Comment: Thanks Airsick, titanium is my answer.  The 'document' -  "Materials for Gas Turbines – An Overview." ( Link > http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs-wm/22905.pdf ) was an excellent  resource.  The question was specific because of the British Airways 777 with GE engine GE-90-85 uncontained explosion at Las Vegas last month.  The NTSB has since said the compressor was the source.    - John King

Comment: @Pondlife I'm not sure that this question should be closed as a duplicate of that question, since this question was asked *first*.

Comment: @JonathanWalters The [usual SE approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/151305) is to keep the question with the best answers, even if it's newer. It's the most pragmatic approach, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Various alloys. In general , I believe even the same stage may have different alloys in various engines. As the air progresses through the compressor it heats and alloys are chosen accordingly. Over the years new alloy modifications are developed ; some more subtle changes are longitudinal grain orientation  and single crystal blades. I have done failure analysis on gas turbines, steam turbines and gas compressors and don't recall which blade went where. However, I never saw an aluminum blade ( or vane). GE , and others, have various 13% Cr steel blades they often used. As far as I know Ti and graphite are only used in the first stage fan. I only worked on older design engines, I expect Ti is used in earlier compression stages. The final stages of compression  are so hot that nickel alloys are used. I mean you need a very specific question to get a specific alloy.